# How to relocate a boot partition?

Tags: 10.10, boot, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 10.10. it is installed in one partition and the boot partition is a separate one. can i relocate the boot partition into the ubuntu partition and if yes how??

Comment: yes.  but if you have to ask it's going to be trouble.  i wouldn't.

Comment: psusi's answer shows you how to boot from the ubuntu partition instead ... do you also want to reclaim the space used by the boot partition? (If it's less than 1GB I would not bother)

Comment: the boot partition is 2 gb and it is completely empty.. it just contains the boot files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple; copy the files there to the root partition, unmount the /boot partition, remove the mount directive for the /boot partition, and reinstall grub:

```
sudo -s
mkdir /newboot
cp -ax /boot /newboot
umount /boot
rmdir /boot
mv /newboot /boot
nano /etc/fstab
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

When you are editing /etc/fstab, locate the line for /boot and remove it.

Comment: im getting this error
`root@ubuntu:~# cp -ax /boot /newboot   
root@ubuntu:~# umount /boot   
umount: /boot: not mounted  
root@ubuntu:~# rmdir /boot   
rmdir: failed to remove '/boot': Directory not empty`  (sorry i donot know how to enter them on different lines)

Comment: @Ashu, you don't appear to have a separate /boot partition...

Comment: But a folder called boot is located on an another partition... once i had formatted that partition and my ubuntu stopped showing up in during booting process...

Comment: the contents of the folder are in this image (http://i51.tinypic.com/atoxf9.png)

Comment: @Ashu, that appears to be your Windows 7 partition with the windows boot loader in its /boot directory.  A /boot partition is a partition that holds your /boot directory ( the one in your root ).

Comment: oh yeah there is a /boot directory in my root ... sorry for troubling you with all this. my bad.i didnt know the other boot directory is for win7.